# i want to display boolean method in jsp for email validation

Tags: java, validation, email, jsp

i got login form which contain username, password and email

when i do not include all the related email part the program manage to run successfully

but when i insert the the form for email
i cannot display the valid email

i have validation method (Validation.java)

```
    public class Validation {
private String username;
private String password;
private String email;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setUsername(String username){
    this.username = username;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public void setEmai(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String validate (String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.contains(username) && s2.equals(password))
        return "VALID";
    else
        return "INVALID";

}
public boolean validateEmail() {
    String emailRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\." + 
            "[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@" +
            "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]" +
            "A-Z]{2,7}$";

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
    return pat.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

for respond.jsp this is my code

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>task 2: login Feedback</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Futura; max-width: 600px">
    <jsp:useBean id="validation" class="com.lab5.task2.Validation" scope="request">
        <jsp:setProperty name="validation" property="username" value='<%=request.getParameter("txtUsername")%>'/>
        <jsp:setProperty name="validation" property="password" value='<%=request.getParameter("txtPassword")%>'/>
        <jsp:setProperty name="validation" property="email" value='<%=request.getParameter("txtEmail")%>'/>
    </jsp:useBean>
<fielset>
    <legend>Validation</legend>
    <p>You entered username as <jsp:getProperty name="validation" property="username"/></p>
    <p>You entered password as <jsp:getProperty name="validation" property="password"/></p>
    </br>
    <p>You are a <%=validation.validate("Amirul","12345")%></p>
    <p> Your email: <jsp:getProperty name="validation" property="email"/>
    <%=validation.validateEmail()%>

</fielset>

</body>
```

i got a problem how to display the valid email
i cannot use

```
    <%=validation.validateEmail("amirul@gmail.com")%>
```

the code will produce error
the error say An exception occurred processing JSP page /Task2/respond.jsp at line 18
which is

```
    <jsp:setProperty name="validation" property="email" value='<%=request.getParameter("txtEmail")%>'/>
```

Comment: i got login form in jsp that simple

Comment: Could you edit the question, I can not understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overload method in class like this

```
public boolean validateEmail(inputemail) {
    String emailRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\." + 
            "[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@" +
            "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]" +
            "A-Z]{2,7}$";

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
    return pat.matcher(inputemail).matches();
}
```

Change method without parameter to

```
public boolean validateEmail() {
    return validateEmail(this.email);
}
```

And you can use  `<%=validation.validateEmail("amirul@gmail.com")%>` in JSP file.